# Removing __NEXT_DATA__ script tag for google bots

Tags: seo, googlebot, next.js, crawl-budget

Our e commerce website is built on next js. We wanted to optimise the bit crawl bandwidth by reducing html size shipped to google bots. We want to treat user and bot differently. As we know bots don’t interact with our page, they only scroll anchor tag href links. Now we as part of next js inner working , for hydration we ship script ‘**NEXT_DATA**’ in HTML response. This script itself is adding 66% overhead in total hmtl size.
How can we remove the NEXT_DATA_ script when user agent is bot? All required anchor tag links are already part of hmtl anyway?

It helps us reduce the html size by 66% and improve google crawl bandwidth significantly

Thnaks

Comment: "We want to treat user and bot differently." - Be wary, this behaviour is called cloaking and can net you a Google penalty in some circumstances.

Comment: okay.. thanks. i agree we must do this cautiously .
do you think removing interactivity and serve static HTML for bots will have negative affects? for example i don't want to ship the filter modules in search page which help user filter the products. is this right way to approach this problem.?

Comment: google's bots have a javascript budget, and can run code to render a page. But if you do want to serve raw HTML then consider pre-rendering and serving that instead. The question remains, is the bot getting the same experience as the user? That's generally what Google wants to see when they crawl.